# python2.7: passing kwargs in instance methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, locals

If I want to pass an indentical list of args from one function to another, I can use the locals function. However this falls over if I'm in an instance method, as self cannot be passed as kwarg. I can create a dict of locals and then delete self. I was wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing this though - it seems to come up quite a lot for me.

```
class MyObj:
    def test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        return [a,b,c,d]

class MyVerboseObj(MyObj):
    def test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        print "RUNNING TEST a=%d"%a
        kwargs = locals()
        del kwargs["self"]
        return MyObj.test(self, **kwargs)

MyVerboseObj().test()
```

Is there a better way to pass the identical list args from MyVerboseObj.test to MyObj.test?

**** UPDATE ****

This is a simplified example to demostrate my question. A more practical example might be this:

```
class GenericShow:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
    def getRenderPath(self, extn="jpg", colspace="rgb"):
        return "%s/render_%s.%s"%(self.path, colspace, extn)
    def hasGenericShowHandler(self):
        try:
            import GenericShowHandler
            return True
        except: pass

class UkShow(GenericShow):
     def getRenderPath(self, extn="jpg", colspace="rgb"):
         if self.hasGenericShowHandler():
             kwargs = locals()
             kwargs.pop("self")
             return GenericShow.getRenderPath(self, **kwargs)
         else:
            return "%s/blah/render_%s.%s"%(path, colspace, extn)

show = UkShow("/jobs/test")
show.hasGenericShowHandler()
print show.getRenderPath()
```

I have a lot of show objects with different vars defined by different modules and different naming conventions - I'm trying to create show objects with common functionality.

Comment: is there a reason you are overriding the method when you want to run the exact same method with the same kwargs in the child class?

Comment: Yes - it because I'm just providing this as an example. I'll update the question, but it's really irrelevant to what I want to know.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to override the parent's function (because you want to use it) - simply avoid overriding it by giving it a different name!

```
class MyObj:
    def base_test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        return [a,b,c,d]

class MyVerboseObj(MyObj):
    def test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        print "RUNNING TEST a=%d"%a
        kwargs = locals()
        del kwargs["self"]
        return self.base_test(**kwargs)

print MyVerboseObj().test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `locals()` is rarely a good idea. This approach is confusing and fragile to modifications on the code, because adding any local variable will mess up your call.

I would go for the more explicit:

```
class MyObj:
    def test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        return [a,b,c,d]

class MyVerboseObj(MyObj):
    def test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        print "RUNNING TEST a=%d"%a
        return MyObj.test(self, a, b, c, d)

MyVerboseObj().test()
```

I know it is tedious, but it avoids some trouble. Plus it is more efficient.

Alternatively, if you are OK with loosing the signature, you could just accept `*args, **kwargs` as parameters to your overriding function:

```
class MyObj:
    def test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        return [a,b,c,d]

class MyVerboseObj(MyObj):
    def test(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "RUNNING TEST"   
        return MyObj.test(self, *args, **kwargs)

MyVerboseObj().test()
```

Accessing `a` in this version would be a bit of a hassle, but since you are not really interested in the arguments in your second example this might be the easier solution.

As a side note: As your inheritance structure becomes more complicated (i.e. multiple inheritance) you might want to start using the [super()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) method:

```
class MyObj:
    def test(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):
        return [a,b,c,d]

class MyVerboseObj(MyObj):
    def test(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "RUNNING TEST"   
        super(MyObj, self).test(*args, **kwargs)

MyVerboseObj().test()
```

Comment: The trouble with this is that in MyVerboseObj.test, if I want to use the locals - like in my example I used the a arg which you lost from your version. I know I can still access it from locals["a"] but this is also error prone and inelegant.